# Creating an XML for Dynamically created Elements

Tags: android, xml, dynamically-generated

I want XML for the `TextViews` and `EditTexts` created *dynamically*. Some *blogs* suggest that there are some *Third Party Libraries* that can do that but I wasn't able to find one. I am basically creating `TextViews` & `EditTexts` *dynamically* in my code on a `button` click.

**Code:**

```
      LinearLayout linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++) {
            Display display = ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                    .getDefaultDisplay();
            int width = display.getWidth() / 3;

            TextView et1 = new TextView(this);
            et1.setBackgroundColor(color.transparent);
            et1.setText("Untitled");
            et1.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            EditText et = new EditText(this);
            et.setHint("Click to add");
            et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT);

            LayoutParams lp1 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            LayoutParams lp2 = new LayoutParams(width,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            // lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, et1.getId());

            linearLayout1.addView(et1, lp2);
            linearLayout1.addView(et, lp2);
```

**XML:**

```
    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/addImage" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:text="Edit" />
```

The question is, how do I achieve the `XML` for the `TextView` & `EditText` as a `String` value? Do I give them `tags` and `ids` *statically* in the *code* or is there any other way?

```
  public static final void writeMapXml(Map val, String name, XmlSerializer out)
  throws XmlPullParserException, java.io.IOException
{
    if (val == null) {
        out.startTag(null, "TextView");
        out.endTag(null, "TextView");
        return;
    }

    Set s = val.entrySet();
    Iterator i = s.iterator();

    out.startTag(null, "TextView");
    if (name != null) {
        out.attribute(null, "name", "TextView");
    }

    out.endTag(null, "TextView");
}
```

Comment: whats the error @MurdocN?

Comment: There is no `error`. I want to generate `XML` for the dynamically generated `TextView` and `EditText`. Asking about how to achieve that.

Comment: You've said what you want to do but not why.  Your approach might be wrong.

Comment: Why do I want the `XML` for the dynamically generated views? So that I can save them in database as a string and retrieve them whenever required.

Comment: @MurdocN its not possible to use such xml,  what would be the value of @+id/scrollView1 in your opinion?

Comment: Someone did it in an application for iOS, said they used some third party library. I failed to find one.

Comment: hmm,  i would like to mention that android is not iOS...

Comment: I know that, but I reckon there might be some library. I read about such libraries on net as well (for android).

Comment: ahaik there is no such way

Comment: Couldn't you just use Java to dynamically build your UI during runtime ? What advantage does the approach you are looking for offer ?

Comment: @user1841702 I guess that's what I did. And there is no advantage as such. The `database` is already present on server and the `xml` field in the table is mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XMLSerializer** provided by android itself is enough to make dynamic XMLs.