# How can I get the underlying XML from a dynamically modified view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Thanks in advance...

I allow users to drag/drop views(text, image, etc) onto a RelativeLayout to create 'presentations'. I would ideally like to extract the resulting xml so the presentation can be saved to a fragment or .axml file, and recreated later either on the same device or a different one. I know I can iterate the children and manually create the xml I need, but it seems to me that since it must exist in the relative layout, that there is a way to extract it. Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: That's something your code would have to handle. There is no persistent underlying xml for Views and layouts. They can be inflated from xml, but during runtime, they are just regular Java Objects, and, AFAIK, Android doesn't offer "deflation".

Comment: Been there, done that. Check out my answer. That's the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extract the XML for dynamically generated views. **But** what you can do is use **XMLSerializer** to make an XML of that view that you're generating. Check out my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636421/creating-an-xml-for-dynamically-created-elements).

To be frank, you can not inflate that XML dynamically (in future if you were going to do that). So, make sure you know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for answering, just not the answer I wanted. :(

Comment: Even I wished it was something else but this is the only way of doing it. Took me a month to figure out this whole thing.

Comment: Hey Psy why do you say that the resulting xml from serialization can't be inflated? Inflater accepts a stream so it's easy to get from DB or wherever. As long as it's structured correctly I don't see a problem. Am testing now. Thanks.

Comment: You can only inflate when the activity/fragment starts and the XML is read and all its components are loaded. Android does not allow us to inflate the view dynamically after it has been inflated, eg: if you try to do it on clicking a button, it won't happen..

Comment: @RussT The reason xml layouts created dynamically can't be inflated with LayoutInflater is because the stream (currently) has to come from a compiled resource, due to the overhead involved. Furthermore, proper layouts can be inflated at any time during runtime; it is not restricted to Activity/Fragment startup. In fact, components like ListView rely on inflating layouts after that happens.

Comment: Yes, those tags are the reason why they can not be inflated dynamically. Thus what you can do is parse the XML and et the values eg: <Type>ImageView</Type> and then create ImageView dynamically.