# How to get the tag type of an Element in java

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, types

I would like to get the tag type of an Element in Java.
For example, for the XML

```
<xml>
<item>
  <content></content>
</item>
</xml>
```

if I want to look for the first tag of the type "item", I need some method of finding all the tags of that specified type.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You need some kind of parser for that.. Like JaxB? Looks like JAXB is not available for Android. So you've to use parsers which supports Android

Comment: You need to check out some xml parser like DOM.

Comment: @user1354678 AFAIK, JAXB isn't available for Android.

Comment: @user1354678 did you check out my answer?

Comment: @UncaughtException, you've tagged me instead of OP

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, default names got me confused. :p

Answer (score 2):

The are many ways to make the XML dynamically:

1. **XmlSerializer**.

*Example:*

```
 public static final void writeMapXml(Map val, String name, XmlSerializer out)
  throws XmlPullParserException, java.io.IOException
{
    if (val == null) {
        out.startTag(null, "TextView");
        out.endTag(null, "TextView");
        return;
    }

    Set s = val.entrySet();
    Iterator i = s.iterator();

    out.startTag(null, "TextView");
    if (name != null) {
        out.attribute(null, "name", "TextView");
    }

    out.endTag(null, "TextView");
}
```

2. StringBuilder using Editable interface.

Example:

```
Editable string= string.append("<Type> " + VALUE
                                + " </Type>" +  "<Text>"
                                + VALUE + "</Text>"+ "<Field>"
                                +  VALUE + "</Field>" );
```

I have actually implemented both of these methods, 2nd one is easier and uses less lines of code.

Reference: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636421/creating-an-xml-for-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp).

Since you need the `<item>` tags under the root `<xml>` tag, the expression you'll need is `xml/item`.

In Android, the way to do this is:
First, get an XPath instance:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
```

Next, get hold of an [`InputSource`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html). Check the link for different ways to do this.

Next, use this to find the nodes:

```
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("xml/item", inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Now, the `NodeList` contains your `<item>` elements.

Comment: None of the class I mentioned here require extra libraries, or what do you mean by 'native' ?